# Getting the value of "on" for radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
var allQuestions = [{
  question1: "What is 1 + 1?",
  choices: ["1", "2", "3", 4],
  correctAnswer: ["2"]
}, {
  question2: "What is 2 + 2?",
  choices: ["6", "2", "3", 4, ],
  correctAnswer: ["4"]
}, {
  question3: "What is 3 + 3?",
  choices: ["3", "6", "9", 12],
  correctAnswer: ["6"]
}];

var newArray = shuffleArray(allQuestions);

function shuffleArray(array) {
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
  return array;
}

function appendQuestions(number) {
  if (newArray == "undefined" || newArray == "null" || newArray.length == 0) {
    document.getElementById("questionForm").innerHTML = "Complete!";
  } else {
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      $("#questionForm").append("<input name='question' type='radio'>" +
        JSON.stringify(newArray[0].choices[i]) + "</input>")
    }
  }
}

$(function() {
  $("#questionList").empty();
  appendQuestions();
  newArray.shift();
})

function isCorrectAnswer() {
  checkedVal = $("input[type=radio][name=question]:checked").val();
  if (checkedVal == newArray[0].correctAnswer) {
    alert("Correct!");
  } else {
    alert("Wrong!");
  }
  alert(checkedVal);
}

$("#submitButton").click(function() {
  isCorrectAnswer();
  $("#questionForm").empty();
  appendQuestions();
  newArray.shift();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <section id='questions'>
    <form id="questionForm">
    </form>
    <div style='clear:both'></div>
    <input id='submitButton' type='button' value='Submit'>
  </section>
</div>
```

First off, sorry for the amount of code pasted. I have no idea if I'm missing some small bug or if I'm just writing the wrong code, so I figured it would be best to post all of it.

I am trying to get the value of a radio button. In the isCorrectAnswer function the first 2 lines are to determine the value of the radio button that is currently checked. The problem is when I alert the value of the radio button, it just says "on". I have searched for the last hour trying to figure out what this means or how to fix it and could not find a thing.

I apologize if this is a stupid question or if it has already been answered.

Comment: Your `radio`s don't have values?

Comment: Wow, you're right. For some reason I thought putting something in the HTML equated to it's value. I added a value="" and it works. I feel like an idiot. Thank you.

Comment: `.innerhtml`  not `val`  or yes, adding a value' will work to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change this line :

```
$("#questionForm").append("<input name='question' type='radio'>" +
         JSON.stringify(newArray[0].choices[i]) + "</input>");
```

To :

```
$("#questionForm").append("<input name='question' type='radio' value='" +
        JSON.stringify(newArray[0].correctAnswer[i]) + "' />"+JSON.stringify(newArray[0].choices[i]));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It certainly did. Thanks so much!